# Why am I recieving Run TIme error 1004 when I am not selecting multiple ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, insert, cut

I am cutting and inserting a column all within the same spreadsheet in VBA, and I am continually getting the error that reads "Run-time error '1004': This can't be done on a multiple range selection. Select a single range and try again." However, I am only cutting a single column. Thi highlighted code is ".Columns(9).Insert".

I have already tried clearing the clipboard before cutting the column with "Application.CutCopyMode=False". I've also already tried cutting H1 to xlDown.

```
'Jeffrey Hughes
'01MAY2019
Option Explicit
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim arr1(2499) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngToFilter As Range
Dim Criteriae(3, 3) As String

Sub RunReport()

'Clears all filters from the WIP & Plan sheets
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").AutoFilterMode Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").AutoFilterMode = False
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").AutoFilterMode Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").AutoFilterMode = False
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Summary").AutoFilterMode Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Summary").AutoFilterMode = False
End If

'Clear all data in the WIP and Plan sheets
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").Range("A1:S2500").Clear
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan").Range("A1:S8500").Clear
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Summary").Range("A1:S2500").Clear

'Load WIP File
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\Dispensing\Production Planning\Supply & KCR\WIP.xml" 'Customer Database Location
Workbooks("WIP").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S2500").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Supply & KCR Production Metrics").Sheets("WIP").Range("C1")
Workbooks("WIP").Close

'Load Plan File
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\Dispensing\Production Planning\Supply & KCR\Plan.xml" 'Customer Database Location
Workbooks("Plan").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:S8500").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Supply & KCR Production Metrics").Sheets("Plan").Range("A1")
Workbooks("Plan").Close

'WIP File
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP")
        .Range("L:L").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("C:C").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("E:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("H:H").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        'Cut col G, and insert into col B
        .Columns(8).Copy
        .Columns(2).Insert
        'Cut C & D and insert into I
        .Columns("C:E").Cut
        .Columns(9).Insert
```

The expected result is column H will become column B and that the previous column B and the columns that were to the right of it will be shifted to the right.

Comment: Do you have any merged cells that might mess up the range? (although then I would expect an error mentioning merged cells.). For testing only (usually avoid select!)... try selecting the ranges to SEE whats happening:.  `End With
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").Columns(8).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").Columns(2).Select
        Selection.Insert
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").Columns("C:E").Select
        Selection.Cut
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP").Columns(9).Select
        Selection.Insert`

Comment: No merged cells, but I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Stackexchange is somewhat different to other sites in that it is intended to be a "Repository of Great answers"... you may like to see the the [tour] page and the [help]. As such, it's probably "good form" to either delete this post, as it doesn't have an answer, or provide more info, or, if you did find the solution, answer it yourself!